# Problem with responsive grid at project pathfinder

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm new at front-end developer actually I'm at course.
And I have problem with my project grid.
I have psd template how this should looks like but completely idk how to make it responsive.

Here is my replit link https://project-pathfinder.patrykszwiec.repl.co
Here is the design : https://imgur.com/a/KHSvutO

How can I make it responsive easy? Actually it good at 3 resolutions but it's not working like it should?

How should I work with psd design to do 1:1 website?

Comment: We are not here to code for you, sorry. Please post a question alongside your code and a description what problems you are facing exactly (best case: use the search before and find a solution yourself...) Also, this will get you started: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries

Comment: you have to read about css media

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.